# Converting from GCC to CMake

Tags: gcc, cmake, pkg-config, cflags

What's the CMake equivalent of:

```
gcc filename.c -o filename $(pkg-config --libs --cflags mylib)
```

I am interested on the `$(pkg-config --libs --cflags mylib)` part, since I already have code that compiles, and I just need to add the `mylib` library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the *FindPkgConfig* module
src: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPkgConfig.html

CMakeLists.txt example:

```
include(FindPkgConfig)

pkg_check_modules(MYLIB REQUIRED mylib)
...
add_executable(filename filename.c)
target_include_directories(filename PUBLIC ${MYLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_compile_options(filename PUBLIC ${MYLIB_CFLAGS})
target_link_libraries(filename ${MYLIB_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: Does the order of the statements matter? `add_executable` has to be in that position, or can it come first or last?

Comment: add_executable(foo ...) (ed or add_library(foo ...)) will generate (i.e. declare) the CMake target *foo* so it must comes before any other target_*() functions after you can put the target_* methods in any order...